# Creating a search interface - android

Tags: android-intent

I am having a doubt in the below paragraph.

When a user executes a search from the search dialog or widget, the system starts your searchable activity and sends it a ACTION_SEARCH intent. This intent carries the search query in the QUERY string extra.

What is string extra in the above paragraphs last line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read about all the details of [Creating a Search Interface](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html) but I'll give you a brief overview of how this works:

First off, a searchable activity is the Activity in your application that performs searches based on a query string and presents the search results.

When the user executes a search in the search dialog or widget, the system starts your searchable activity and delivers it the search query in an [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) with the [ACTION_SEARCH](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEARCH) action.

Your searchable activity retrieves the query from the intent's [QUERY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/SearchManager.html#QUERY) extra, then searches your data and presents the results.